# How do I share Redis key/values across multiple instances with rackup/Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra, rackup

I'm trying to use Redis as my session store, which seem to work just fine. However I can't figure out how to let multiple instances of Sinatra access the same session. This is what I have in my config.ru:

```
require 'redis-rack'

use Rack::Session::Redis, :redis_server => "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST']}:6379/0"
```

I must be missing an argument to set this, but the documentation is lacking for this case:
https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rack

Maybe that's not what I want to achieve this behavior?

The end goal is to be deploying my Sinatra application with docker to a clustered environment so I can release new versions without downtime. So whatever let's me share the rack session between multiple instances works. I suppose I could create a redis object manually and not use the session keyword, just seems like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: What does your Sinatra app look like? Particularly the sessions bit.

Comment: The only thing I do with the session is stuff like `session[:var] = "value"`. I have tried doing things like `enable :sessions` but that doesn't seem to change anything. I assume it would if I wasn't using the Rack::Session gem bits...

Comment: we need more info here, show us your server so we can reproduce.

Comment: Well I sure feel silly now. I stripped out all the code to a basic example to provide a way to reproduce it. Turns out, that worked. In all of my toying around with this, I had a line setting the session to Rack::Session:Pool. Removing that line let Rack::Session::Redis work as expected.

Thanks for responding and forcing me to look at the code at a different angle, I was struggling.